# Difference between two media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

According to [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/), the media queries for an iPhone 4 is:

```
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}
```

My question is, what is the difference between `/* Portrait and Landscape */` media query and the `/* Portrait */`, `/* Landscape */` media queries? Wouldn't using `/* Portrait and Landscape */` be enough?

Comment: depends whether you want to target *only* landscape or portrait

Comment: Oh so if I want to target both I can use /* Portrait and Landscape */?

Comment: If someone needs to show different styles according to portrait/landscape mode can do it. Otherwise don't use `orientation` attribute

Answer (score 1):

`orientation` is an additional condition depending on whether or not you wish to apply those styles for a view port currently in a portrait/landscape display.

The `max-device-width: 480px` property will apply even if you're in `landscape` mode.

For example you might not wish to change the styling in landscape mode due to there being less space "[above the fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Above_the_fold)". In portrait mode you would be more likely to use a chunky header for example, whereas with landscape you may wish to use a more compact header to reduce real-estate usage.

---

In terms of the CSS Tricks documentation, they are just showing how you can target both portait & landscape, or just one of the other.

Comment: ... just a note. Its not the actual *orientation* of display. Instead it determines if the viewport is [*wider or taller*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation) at any given point.